# XmlWriter including namespace\schema for each tag

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xmlwriter

I need to create a file in XML using XmlWriter including for each tag the namespace\schema.
First I have a class produced by xsd schema file, I create the class with all objects and finally I serialize the class writing xml:

```
myclass root = new myclass();
root.val1 = "temp1";
root.val2 = "temp2";

[...]

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine("myfile.xml"), s))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
```

the problem is that it creates the tags like that:

```
<Message>
    <val1> temp1 </val1>
    <val2> temp2 </val2>
<Message>
```

I want to write the tags as:

```
<temp:Message>
    <temp:val1> temp1 </val1>
    <temp:val2> temp2 </val2>
<temp:Message>
```

can I use some attribute in my class to add `temp:` starting tags?

I need also to add to my root tag some namespace:

```
<temp:Message
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="myxml.xsd"
    xmlns:stf="urn:oecd:ties:stf:v4"
    xmlns:mesage="urn:oecd:ties:cbc:v1"
    xmlns:iso="urn:oecd:ties:isocbctypes:v1"
    version="1.0">
```

so I need to add to root class:

```
1) xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
2) xsi:schemaLocation="myxml.xsd"
3) xmlns:mesage="urn:oecd:ties:cbc:v1"
4) etc...
```

how can I do that?

Comment: dont forget to upvot/accept if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

you can attache `temp` by doing as below , attach namespace with you xml

```
var xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xsn.Add("temp", "http://namespaceforxml");
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
Message msg = new Message(); 
// Writing a file requires a TextWriter.
TextWriter t = new StreamWriter(filename);
s.Serialize(t,msg,ns);
t.Close();
```

decorate calss as below

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Message", Namespace = "//namespaceforxml")]
public class Message
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "val1")]
    public string val1{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and what is the object to attach xsn variable you created?

Comment: tomorrow I'll try at work your code but I need also to add to root xml tag.

Comment: @ezechiele2517 - if you want extra root tag then you need to put you class which is Message in another class...example Public class Root { public Message message {get; set;}} this will do

Comment: I added in the second part of my first post the code to explain what I need. Can you look it? Thanks